# Capture spacebar press to pause Timer C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I have a windows form which is a countdown Timer.  What is the best way for me to pause the timer by pressing the spacebar on the keyboard.  I have three buttons on the form for start, pause and stop and res-set.  However I also want to pause, restart on press off spacebar.  I tried to add a fourth button and then made it hidden on the form and added the following code (changed the EventArgs to KeyEventArgs:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
           // Pause the timer.  
       timer1.Enabled = false;
       paused = true;
       Start.Enabled = true;
       Pause.Enabled = false;  
    }
```

However when i try to run this i get the error - No overload for 'button1_Click matches 
delegate System.EventHandler

Is there something I have missed or a better way off doing this.

Any Help/Advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Click` event doesn't take a `KeyEventArgs`.

You're looking for the form's `KeyPress` event.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for your reply - i changed the code to:

        private void button1_Click(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == Keys.Space)
                // Pause the timer.  
                timer1.Enabled = false;
            paused = true;
            Start.Enabled = true;
            Pause.Enabled = false;
        }

however it does not like the e.KeyChar == Keys.Space (Operator == cannot be applied to operands of type char and System.Windows.Forms.Keys.  Is there something else I need to do?  Many Thanks

Comment: I don't think you understand what SLaks meant, you are trying to do this in a Button click event, you need to do it on the KeyPress or KeyDown event.

Comment: @Colly: Use `' '`, which is a `char`

Comment: @hdougie - I do not see a KeyPress or Keydown event - can you tell me what this is on the Toolbox?

Comment: It's an event, not a control.  You will see it in the property grid.

Comment: @Slaks - I had tried that - if i try if (e.KeyChar == " ") it does not like that as it still picks up " " as a string.  I then tried e.KeyChar.ToString() == " " which it also didnt like

Comment: You need a character literal: `' '`

Comment: @Slaks - ok I see what you mean about the ' ' instead of " ". I think I should use the KeyPress or Keydown events - however I do not see these in the property grid (do I still need to add a button) and is it somewere in the property window - the button 1 i did and and made invisible I dont see anything in the property window for event?  Thanks for all your help so far